# SLURM: restrict GPU access only to SLURM

Tags: gpu, slurm

I have a single machine (Ubuntu 16.04 Server) with
4 TitanX GPUs. This will be a lab machine on which
students will learn about CUDA and stuff. I installed
SLURM because I want a tool to schedule and enqueue jobs
automatically based on GPU availability.

For this to work, students should have access to GPUs only
through SLURM. Is there a way to achieve this in single-machine
setup, where SLURM and cards are on the same host?

Students should only access cards through:

```
# srun --gres ...
```

I know about `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` but this variable is ignores when set
by root or even each user. It only works when set per process, for example
`deviceQuery` from CUDA Samples:

```
# CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2 /usr/local/cuda-9.0/extras/demo_suite/deviceQuery
```

And it might be used by the SLURM itself to restrict cards, so it is (rather) not a solution.

Best Regards
K.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all access to the nVidia cards goes through `/dev/nvidia*`, so it ought to be doable with permissions. Having never used any of the software involved, though, I'll just leave this as a pointer, I won't hazard to guess how to implement.

Comment: Without completely disabling logins to the node that contains the GPUs, I don't know of an easy way to do with within Slurm

Answer (score 0):

create a PrologSlurmctld (https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#OPT_PrologSlurmctld) script which set the access to the GPU (/dev/nvidia* devices) with setfacl to the current user